# Needing system defined function to select updated or unmatched new records from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a live data table in which the old values are placed,in a new table i am moving data from that live table to this one how to find updated or new records that are inserted or updated in new table with out using except,checksum(binary_checksum) and join ,i am looking for a solution using System Defined Function.

Comment: Please show the code here that you have tried.

Comment: i havent tried yet

Comment: Read this then update your question please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: sql server management studio

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is interesting as the best solutions are to use `EXCEPT` or a `FULL JOIN`. What you are trying to do is what is referred to as an `left anti semi join`. Here's a [good article about the topic](http://daleburnett.com/2011/10/semi-joins-and-anti-joins/).

Note this sample data and the solutions (note that my solution that does not use EXCEPT or a join is the last solution):

```
-- sample data 
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.orig') is not null drop table dbo.orig;
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.new')  is not null drop table dbo.new;
create table dbo.orig (someid int, col1 int, constraint uq_cl_orig unique (someid, col1));
create table dbo.new  (someid int, col1 int, constraint uq_cl_new unique (someid, col1));

insert dbo.orig values (1,100),(2,110),(3,120),(4,2000)
insert dbo.new  values (1,100),(2,110),(3,122),(5,999);
```

Here's the EXCEPT version

```
select someid 
from
(
  select * from dbo.new except
  select * from dbo.orig
) n
union -- union "distict" 
select someid
from
(
  select * from dbo.orig except 
  select * from dbo.new
) o;
```

Here's a FULL JOIN Solution which will also tell you if the record was removed, changed or added:

```
select
  someid   = isnull(n.someid, o.someid), 
  [status] =
    case 
      when count(isnull(n.someid, o.someid)) > 1 then 'changed'
      when max(n.col1) is null then 'removed' else 'added'
    end
from dbo.new n
full join dbo.orig o 
  on n.col1=o.col1 and n.someid = o.someid
where n.col1 is null or o.col1 is null
group by isnull(n.someid, o.someid);
```

But, because those efficient solutions are not an option - you will need to go with a NOT IN or NOT EXISTS subquery.... And ***because it has to be a function***, I am encapsulating the logic into a function.

```
create function dbo.newOrChangedOrRemoved()
returns table as return

-- get the new records
select someid, [status] = 'new'
from dbo.new n
where n.someid not in (select someid from dbo.orig)
union all
-- get the removed records
select someid, 'removed'
from dbo.orig o
where o.someid not in (select someid from dbo.new)
union all
-- get the changed records
select someid, 'changed' 
from dbo.orig o
where exists
(
  select *
  from dbo.new n
  where o.someid = n.someid and o.col1 <> n.col1
);
```

Results:

```
someid      status
----------- -------
5           new
4           removed
3           changed
```